# Eclipse RCP drop file from external explorer not accepted

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application which should open files via drag & drop from the windows explorer. So I implemented this:

```
public class ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {

    @Override
    public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addEditorAreaTransfer(FileTransfer.getInstance());
        configurer.configureEditorAreaDropListener(editorDropListener);
        return new ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(configurer);
    }
[...]
}
```

`editorDropListener` is of type `DropTargetAdapter` and implements the `drop()` method.

Now if I drag a file from my explorer into my application, I get that "Windows Unavailable" mouse icon and the drop will not work. The `editorDropListener.drop()` is not called.

If I drag the file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> key pressed, I get the "windows copy" mouse icon. The drop works and `editorDropListener.drop()` is successfully called.

Where can I configure, which kind of drop is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem has not been solve from above. I just have look up the apis of DND and solve this problem, eliminate the Ctrl or Alt press.
[Drag and Drop](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html)
We just need to add some code in you EditorAreaDropAdapter:

```
        @Override
public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
    super.dragEnter(event);
}
```

event.detail has to be set as DND.DROP_COPY for acceptence.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I am not working with that anymore, so I cannot confirm this as correct answer. Can anyone else do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little more complicated than that, as the editor area does not accept a MOVE DND request.

Have a look at `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.EditorAreaDropAdapter` for the details.

Comment: thankyou. in the end i want to differ between a drag with shift or ctrl pressed or not. so i always end up finding implementations which hardcode any drag-drop event as copy, to make it work with eclipse. So it is the editor and i have to "configure" it to accept more than copy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your listener. it will work.

```
                @Override
        public void dragEnter(final DropTargetEvent event) {

            if (event.detail == DND.DROP_DEFAULT) {
                if ((event.operations & DND.DROP_COPY) != 0) {
                    event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
                } else {
                    event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
                }
            }
        }
```